# Calling function from watch window/Command window results in identifier "x" is undefined in MSVS 2013

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I've noticed that there are functions that cannot be called from the MSVS 2013/2010 debugger's watch/command windows.  One such function is [GetProp()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633564%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Considering that this is an API, it must be exported from the dll "User32.dll".

I've seen references to prepending `{,,_dllName.dll_}` to a watch variable, but I've not been able to find the MS link that actually describes what it does, what the other parameters are as I have no name for this prefix.  In any case, it doesn't appear to work.

Does anyone know how to access these functions from the debugger so that I don't have make temporary variables in the source and to do a recompile?